# Best way to sum() values between two dates (where the second date is stored as a value in the next row) - postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sum, subquery

I am a little bit stuck with an issue I'm having with a psql query. I know how I'd approach this using a loop etc, but have hit a wall in SQL as I'm no expert.

If we imagine that there are 3 terms per school year. Each child may recieve an allowance for lunches each month. I would like to SUM() the allowance for each month, from the start of the term up until the next term.

Where I am stuck is that the date of the next term is a value in the next row of data in the `terms` table.

I have something like this:

```
SELECT
    terms."startDate",
    COALESCE((
        SELECT
            SUM("lunch")
        FROM
            "allowance"
        WHERE
            TO_CHAR(terms."startDate", 'YYYY-MM') >= TO_CHAR("date", 'YYYY-MM')
        AND
            TO_CHAR(terms."startDate", 'YYYY-MM') < TO_CHAR(??? HELP ???, 'YYYY-MM')
    ),0) AS "lunchMoney"
FROM "schoolTerms" AS terms
...
```

Where I have put `TO_CHAR(??? HELP ???, 'YYYY-MM')` I would like to reference the start date of the childs next term. I have looked into using a `LEAD()` method but couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want and join and aggregation:

```
select t.startdate, t.enddate, sum(a.lunch) as lunch_money
from schoolterms t
inner join allowance a on a.date >= t.startdate and a.date < t.enddate
group by t.startdate, t.enddate
```

This puts each allowance in the terms it belongs, and then aggregate by term. You might want a `left join`, if there may be terms without any allowance.

Your current query gives no clue about what a "child" is. Presumably, that should be a column in `allowance`, that you might want to put in the `select` and `group by` clauses.

---

If you want to compute the `end_date` as the "next" `start_date`, then use `lead()`:

```
select t.startdate, t.enddate, sum(a.lunch) as lunch_money
from (
    select start_date, 
        lead(startdate) over(order by startdate) enddate
    from schoolterms
) t
inner join allowance a 
    on  a.date >= t.startdate 
    and (a.date < t.enddate or t.enddate is null)
group by t.startdate, t.enddate
```

Comment: Currently the `enddate` is not a value in the table, instead it is the `startdate` in the next row. This is where I'm having trouble.

Also to clarify - by 'child' I don't mean it in the programmatic sense, but in the sense of a baby/child/kid etc. I know that was probably confusing